# Python and closing windows/functions and tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, widget, exit

I'm trying to understand how to close things in my script but if I make a frame to contain tkinter's widgets and stuff, when I run the code no object is printed on screen... so, putting widgets in the root window seems to be a mandatory choice.
As a beginner, the only way I found to command a closing function is:

```
def read_note():
    def close_readnote():
        text_box.destroy()
        lbl_readnote.destroy()
        btn_close_readnote.destroy()

root.title("Reader of something")
lbl_readnote = Label(root, text="Leggi note", font=20)
lbl_readnote.pack(pady=25)

text_box = Text(root)
text_box.pack(expand=True)
text_box.config(state='disabled')

btn_close_readnote = Button(root, text="x", command=close_readnote)
btn_cls_readnote.pack(side=RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

How would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: You say if you make a frame no object is printed on the screen. The code you posted doesn't illustrate that. There's nothing to prevent you from using as many frames as you want to organize your widgets. In fact, that's exactly why frames exist.

Comment: `close_readnote()` is a nested function inside `read_note()`, so you cannot access it outside `read_note()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, here's two methods I use to close windows:

Closing function:

```
# Closing command
def on_closing(self):
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        self.destroy()
```

Using a "quit" button:

```
quit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.on_closing)
quit_button.grid(row=10, column=4, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='E')
```

Asking user if they'd like to quit upon using the closing button at the top right of the widget:

```
# Tkinter protocol for x close
self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
```

This is using object-oriented programming, which I find helpful for tkinter programming, but you could remove the self references. You can include both methods within your class.